# Google places nearbySearch() returns invalid_request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have the following code:

```
 if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        var request = {
            location: pos,
            radius: 500,
            types: ['store']
        };

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        function createMarker(place) {
          var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              createMarker(results[i]);
            }
          }
        }
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    });
  }
```

nearbySearch returns:
"INVALID_REQUEST", "NOT_FOUND", "OK" "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", "REQUEST_DENIED", "UNKNOWN_ERROR", "ZERO_RESULTS"
but when I use coords given here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places instead of currentposition it works all right. When I'm trying other coords it returns given above errors, what's wrong?

Comment: this code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working just fine.
It could be a problem with your browser not allowing use of your current location since the coordinates given in the example are working for you. Have a look at the location settings of your browser or try another browser.

Comment: I don't know why, but all of these:
pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316); //example data
pos = new google.maps.LatLng(52.240836, 21.015358); // Warsaw data
pos = new google.maps.LatLng(41.89001, -87.627754); // Chicago data
returns "INVALID_REQUEST", "NOT_FOUND", "OK" "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", "REQUEST_DENIED", "UNKNOWN_ERROR", "ZERO_RESULTS",
and only using the first one (example data), I get some markers on my map.

Comment: I've found mistake, markers were set, but map was still centered on pyrmont, so markers were not visible.